# Proof Verification/Doubt: Showing $f(x)=1/x^2$ is not uniformly continuous on $(0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity, uniform-continuity

Show that $f(x)=1/x^2$ is not uniformly continuous on $(0,\infty)$

So I was trying to attempt this question and did the proof as follows:

$f(x)$ is not defined at the point $x=0$. Then, by the continuous extension theorem, $f(x)$ is not uniformly continuous on the interval $(0,\infty)$

I checked the answer to this question in the solution manual, and this was not the approach they used. Rather, they used the non uniform continuity sequential criteria.

My question is, is my proof correct? I am particularly concerned about the interval being $(0,\infty)$ rather than some interval $(a,b)$ where $b \in \mathbb{R}$, so I'm now unsure if the continuous extension theorem is even applicable at all in this case.

Thank you.

Comment: $f(x)=\frac xx$ is not defined at the point $x=0$, but it is uniformly continuous on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Does this imply that the continuous extension theorem is only valid iff our interval is of the form $(a,b)$ where both $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is not whether the function is defined at $0$ but rather whether it can be *extended by continuity* there.  The key lemma you want to use here is that if $f$ is uniformly continuous on a bounded open interval $(a,b)$ then it can be extended by continuity to the extremities $a$ and $b$, i.e., defined there in such a way that the extended function is continuous on the closed interval $[a,b]$.

Then show that $\frac{1}{x^2}$ cannot be extended by continuity at $0$ and you are done.

Comment: Thank you! So you say that I can use that theorem to prove this. You said that the issue is not of whether the function is defined at $0$. What I had in mind was that, for a function to be continuous at, say $a$, must it not be defined at $a$? Wouldn't it be sufficient to show that it is not defined at that point to claim it is discontinuous at that point? Thank you.

Comment: True, that's why we are not talking about continuity of a function itself at $0$, but rather the (one-sided) continuity of a possible extension to the closed interval.

Comment: Haven't read about the idea of one sided continuity anywhere! Can you formalise it? But it makes sense to say that it wouldn't be continuous there either, no? Also, do I show that $1/x^2$ cannot be extended by continuity at $0$ by the use of sequential criteria for discontinuity?

Comment: An explanation of one-sided continuity can be found in [this textbook, page 132](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~keisler/calc.html).

Comment: If $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$ could be extended by continuity to a value $f(0)=L$ say, then for each sequence $(u_n)$ converging to zero, the sequence of values $f(u_n)$ would have to converge to $L$, which it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and your time!

Answer (score 7):

In a comment, A.Asad has clarified:

> **Theorem 1** (The Continuous Extension Theorem): If $I=(a,b)$ is an interval, then $f:I\to\mathbb{R}$ is a uniformly continuous function on $I$ if and only if $f$ can be defined at the endpoints $a$ and $b$ such that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$.

Using this theorem, you need to show that $f(0)$ *cannot* be defined so that $f$ is continuous. Simply saying that "$f(0)$ is not defined" is not quite enough. Something like "$\lim\limits_{x\to0}f(x)$ does not exist, so there is no value of $f(0)$ that would make $f$ continuous at $0$" would be good.

Regarding your concern at the end of your question: if $f$ is not uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$ then it is not uniformly continuous on $(0,\infty)$.

---

We can simply use the definition of uniform continuity. Note that
$$
f\left(\frac1{\sqrt{n+2}}\right)-f\left(\frac1{\sqrt{n\vphantom{1}}}\right)=2
$$
yet
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\frac1{\sqrt{n\vphantom{1}}}-\frac1{\sqrt{n+2}}\right|
&=\frac2{\sqrt{n\vphantom{1}}\sqrt{n+2}\left(\sqrt{n\vphantom{1}}+\sqrt{n+2}\right)}\\
&\le\frac1{n^{3/2}}
\end{align}
$$
So we can't find a $\delta\gt0$ so that $|x-y|\le\delta\implies|f(x)-f(y)|\le1$.

Comment: Even if Tietze was applicable somehow it would be like killing a fly with an AC130.

Comment: It seems pretty clear that the theorem he had in mind is this: If $E$ is a subset of a metric space and $f$ is uniformly continuous on $E$ then $f$ extends to a continuous function on $\overline E$.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your answer and I'm referring to this theorem: Theorem 1 (The Continuous Extension Theorem): If I=(a,b) is an interval, then f:I→R is a uniformly continuous function on I if and only if f can be defined at the endpoints a and b such that f is continuous on [a,b]. Can you answer keeping this theorem in mind? Also, I haven't been exposed to topology or metric spaces at all so it makes very little sense to me, if any...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Thanks. The theorem they were considering was a bit more basic, though the theorem you cite is much closer than Tietze. However, I thought it would be good to ask for some clarification so that my answer might be understandable (mentioning metric spaces and closures might not be understood).

Comment: @A.Asad: although I have quoted this theorem in my answer, you might want to state it in your question for better clarity.

Comment: @robjohn, Thank you so much for the clarification. Yes, I realise that I simply stated rather than formalised my argument. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}$$ is uniformly continuous on the interval $[3, \infty)$ and is not uniformly continuous on the interval $(0, 3)$.

Answer (score -1):

$f$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,\infty)$ for any $a>0$ so you can concentrate on what happens near $0$. The correct argument is the following: if $f$ is uniformly continuous and $x_n$ decreases to $0$ then $\{f(x_n)\}$ is a Cauchy sequence (as you can see from definition of uniform continuity) hence convergent; since $\frac 1 {x_n^{2}} \to \infty$ we have a contradiction. I believe this is what you had in mind but the way you expressed the idea is not correct.

Comment: $f=1/x^2$ is uniformly continuous on $[1,\infty)$. It isn't uniformly continuous on $(0,1]$

Comment: @Piyush Divyanakar Did you read my answer? I am showing exactly what you are saying: that the function is uniformly continuous on $[1,\infty)$ but not on $(0,1)$